# Token replacement when deploying using Gradle

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-dhf, ml-gradle

We have some environment specific configurations that we want to deploy.

We're using ML 9, together with the gradle 4.8 plus:
- ml-data-hub plugin 3.0.0
- ml-gradle plugin 3.6.3
- saliman properties plugin 1.4.6

I've created two resources (JSON and XQuery) under plugins/config (our code resides under the plugins directory) to use tokens:

```
{
  "environment" : "%%DATABASE%%",
  "built-from"  : "%%buildFile%%",
  "finalprop"   : "%%mlJobPort%%"
}
```

And:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
module namespace tc = "http://my.company.com/config/test-config";
(: test to verify whether tokens are expanded in XQuery resources :)
declare variable $_SOME_VARIABLE as xs:string := "%%mlHost%%";
```

We have verified the tokens to be present in the token replace map (using both the mlPrintTokens and the --debug option to mlReloadModules), this is not the issue. 
However, in the deployed versions of the XQuery and the JSON document, the replacement tokens are never expanded to their actual values.

What is missing from our current setup to allows us to replace the tokens correctly with their environment specific values?

Comment: DHF overrides some parts of the ml-gradle plugin; it's possible that's causing a problem. Added the marklogic-dhf tag.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, we applied a workaround to this problem by copying a file into our build structure and applying Apache Ant's ReplaceTokens filter along the way.
Should somebody have a cleaner way to achieve the goal, we'd love to hear it.
//Milco